# how to send push notification to multiple android devices

Tags: android, delphi, google-cloud-messaging, push

i followed the tut in this [link](http://delphi.org/2014/12/mobile-push-notifications-without-a-baas/) about how to send push notification using GCM,i managed to send and receive notifications from the app, however, i can't receive notifications from different android devices, the device only send and receive to itself. i need it to send to all devices using the same project id? 
this is the code i've used

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
    System.SysUtils, System.Classes, GCMNotification, IndyPeerImpl,
   IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack, IdSSL, IdSSLOpenSSL
  ;

type
  TDataModule1 = class(TDataModule)
  procedure DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
  procedure DataModuleDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    {$IFDEF ANDROID}
    gcmn: TGCMNotification;
    {$ENDIF}
  public
    { Public declarations }
    function GetDeviceRegistrationId: string;
    function PushMessage(Pushmessage: string): string;
  end;

var
  DataModule1: TDataModule1;

  const
  YOUR_GCM_SENDERID = '1232010xxxxxx';
  YOUR_API_ID = 'AIzaSyBzvpTa-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'FMX.Controls.TControl'}

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TDataModule1.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  isRegistered : boolean;
begin

  isRegistered := true;
  {$IFDEF ANDROID}
  try
    gcmn := TGCMNotification.Create(self);
    gcmn.SenderID := YOUR_GCM_SENDERID;
    isRegistered := gcmn.DoRegister;
  except
  end;
  {$ENDIF}

end;

procedure TDataModule1.DataModuleDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  gcmn.Free();
  {$ENDIF}
end;

function TDataModule1.GetDeviceRegistrationId: string;
begin
  {$IFDEF ANDROID}
  result := gcmn.RegistrationID;
  {$ELSE}
  result := 'Mobile Test';
  {$ENDIF}
end;

function TDataModule1.PushMessage(Pushmessage : string):string;
const
  sendUrl = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
var
  Params: TStringList;
  AuthHeader: STring;
  idHTTP: TIDHTTP;
  SSLIOHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  idHTTP := TIDHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    SslIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    idHTTP.IOHandler := SSLIOHandler;
    idHTTP.HTTPOptions := [];
    Params := TStringList.Create;
    try
      Params.Add('registration_id='+ GetDeviceRegistrationId());
      Params.Values['data.message'] := Pushmessage;
      idHTTP.Request.Host := sendUrl;
      AuthHeader := 'Authorization: key=' + YOUR_API_ID;
      idHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Add(AuthHeader);
      IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
      result := idHTTP.Post(sendUrl, Params);
    finally
      Params.Free;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(idHTTP);
  end;

end;
end.
```

and this the code in the button

```
DataModule1.PushMessage(Edit1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to Delphi but it looks like you'll need to modify the `PushMessage` method.

Change `registration_id` to `registration_ids` in Params.Add(...) and make sure `GetDeviceRegistrationId()` returns an array of the intended registration ID recipients.

Comment: but why the copies of the same application dosent receive the notification ? it send and receive to iteslf!

Comment: Does your sender have all the registration IDs of these other devices? You should also get a response when you send the message. It's a JSON response that shows successes and failures, if any.

Comment: yes i have the IDs,i tried to send push message through looping IDs in a lisview but it didnt work !!                                                                                                                                     var
n:integer;
begin
for n := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count - 1 do
DataModule1.PushMessage(ListView1.ItemAppearanceName[n]);

Comment: plz take a look now @Koh